# Для каждого элемента Listview повесить listener

Tags: javafx, listview

Собственно с помощью Last fm API считываю вики инфу о исполнителе и в `langs` считываю имя исполнителей с моего пк и в итоге слушатель вешается на все элементы `ListView` как повесить разные слушатели на элементы `ListView`  ??

```
    ObservableList<String> langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<String> langsListView = new ListView<String>(langs);
    List<String> idk = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void ArtistsWeb() {
        Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("tst");
        String key = "d5caa39183e72b2d5d5f7f1b600c286b"; //this is the key used in the Last.fm API examples
        for (Mp3data data : mp3data) {


            langs.add(data.getArtist());
            Artist artist = Artist.getInfo(data.getArtist(), key);
            idk.add(artist.getWikiText());

        }
        for (String  track:idk) {
            langsListView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {

                FlowPane root = new FlowPane();

                Label label1 = new Label();
                label1.setText(track);

                Label label2 = new Label();

                root.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2);


                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
                scene.getStylesheets().add("sample/style/styles4.css");
                Stage window = new Stage();
                window.setTitle("WEB");
                window.setScene(scene);
                window.show();
            });


            FlowPane root = new FlowPane(langsListView);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("sample/style/styles2.css");
            Stage window = new Stage();
            window.setTitle("WEB");
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил

```
public void ArtistsWeb() {
            ObservableList<String> langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ListView<String> langsListView = new ListView<String>(langs);
        Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("tst");
        String key = "d5caa39183e72b2d5d5f7f1b600c286b"; //this is the key used in the Last.fm API examples
        for (Mp3data data : mp3data) {


            langs.add(data.getArtist());

        }
                langsListView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {

                    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
                    Artist artist = Artist.getInfo(langsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), key);

                    Label label1 = new Label();
                    label1.setText(artist.getWikiText());

                    Label label2 = new Label();

                    root.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2);


                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add("sample/style/styles4.css");
                    Stage window = new Stage();
                    window.setTitle("WEB");
                    window.setScene(scene);
                    window.show();
                })
```

;